# How to avoid double serialization of JSON when triggering Lambda from SQS?

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, python-3.8

I created an API with AWS API Gateway. One of the endpoints writes a message into an SQS queue. The content is a JSON which is created by a mapping template. The API endpoint (POST) receives a payload in the body as JSON. I need the API params as well as the body in a Lambda function. I use SQS to ensure each transaction is handled eventually by a Lambda function. So, I designed the mapping template in API gateway as follows:

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
#set($allParams = $input.params())
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={"params" : {
    #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
    "$type" : {
      #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
      "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
      #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
      #end
    }
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
    "context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "domain" : "$context.domainName",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }, "body": $input.body}
```

If I then call the API with a valid JSON in the body it is added to my SQS queue as valid JSON:

```
{"params" : {
        "path" : {
            "userid" : "4711"
                }
    ,        "querystring" : {
          }
    ,        "header" : {
            "Accept" : "*\/*"
      ,            "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip, deflate, br"
      ,            "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto" : "https"
      ,            "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer" : "true"
      ,            "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer" : "false"
      ,            "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer" : "false"
      ,            "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer" : "false"
      ,            "CloudFront-Viewer-Country" : "DE"
      ,            "Content-Type" : "application\/json"
      ,            "Host" : "api.example.com"
      ,            "Postman-Token" : "62c71606-13df-4b52-b772-594fa0af5ced"
      ,            "Referer" : "http:\/\/api.example.com\/dev\/queue\/sqs\/4711"
      ,            "User-Agent" : "PostmanRuntime\/7.25.0"
      ,            "Via" : "1.1 90cf045072333c2f671297de3161846f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)"
      ,            "X-Amz-Cf-Id" : "6lB7_0-mbznpoTWPc_ba0ngmaJ0VUTEUsSDwISO0YTgwoJMZ4D170g=="
      ,            "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" : "Root=1-5ee0cd7b-45119685e51905886208e054"
      ,            "X-Forwarded-For" : "130.100.136.74, 130.176.0.160"
      ,            "X-Forwarded-Port" : "443"
      ,            "X-Forwarded-Proto" : "https"
                }
          },
    "context" : {
    "account-id" : "",
    "api-id" : "gufdrsc4x0",
    "api-key" : "",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "",
    "caller" : "",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "",
    "domain" : "api.example.com",
    "http-method" : "POST",
    "stage" : "dev",
    "source-ip" : "160.100.136.74",
    "user" : "",
    "user-agent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.25.0",
    "user-arn" : "",
    "request-id" : "28b1201f-cf7d-45e5-8f57-6b54609a212e",
    "resource-id" : "4yw0f8",
    "resource-path" : "/queue/sqs/{userid}"
    }, "body": {"order": {
    "access_allowed": true,
    "business_name": null,
    "business_vat_number": null,
    "buyer_address1": null,
    "buyer_address2": null,
    "buyer_city": null,
    "buyer_country": "GB",
    "buyer_email": "mrbuyer@gmail.com",
    "buyer_ip_address": "127.0.0.1",
    "buyer_name": "Mr Buyer",
    "buyer_postcode": null,
    "buyer_region": null,
    "cart": {
        "cart_items": [
            {
                "download_attempts": 3,
                "product": {
                    "id": 2811,
                    "license_type": "generated",
                    "member_types": [
                        "digital"
                    ],
                    "name": "My Product",
                    "price": "£15.00",
                    "product_image_url": null,
                    "product_type": "digital",
                    "shopify_variant_id": null
                },
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_rate": 20.0,
                "valid_until": "2016-02-04T10:59:25Z"
            }
        ],
        "completed_checkout_at": "2016-01-05T10:59:24Z"
    },
    "discount": null,
    "dispatched_at": null,
    "download_url": "http://transactions.sendowl.com/orders/123456/download/XXX",
    "eu_resolved_country": "GB",
    "eu_reverse_charge": null,
    "for_subscription": false,
    "gateway": "Stripe",
    "gift_deliver_at": null,
    "gift_order": false,
    "giftee_email": null,
    "giftee_name": null,
    "id": "0000123456",
    "licenses": [],
    "order_custom_checkout_fields": [],
    "paypal_email": null,
    "price_at_checkout": "£15.00",
    "receiver_email": "mrbuyer@gmail.com",
    "receiver_name": null,
    "settled_affiliate_fee": "£5.00",
    "settled_currency": "GBP",
    "settled_gateway_fee": "£0.38",
    "settled_gross": "£18.00",
    "settled_tax": "£3.00",
    "state": "complete",
    "subscription_management_url": null,
    "tag": null,
    "transactions": [
        {
            "alternate_pay_method_note": null,
            "created_at": "2016-01-05T10:59:24Z",
            "gateway_transaction_id": "ch_fake001",
            "net_price": "£15.60",
            "payment_currency": "GBP",
            "payment_gateway_fee": "£0.38",
            "payment_gross": "£18.00",
            "payment_tax": "£3.00",
            "refund": false
        }
    ],
    "unsubscribe_url": "http://transactions.sendowl.com/orders/123456/unsubscribe/XXX",
    "validity_statement": "This link may be used up to 3 times before 2016-02-04 10:59:25 UTC when it will expire."
}}}
```

The SQS then triggers a Lambda function. This function needs the data in the Records[0]['body]. But it seems to be double serialized somewhere between SQS and Lambda. All entries have escaped quotes (\"), making it impossible to read it because it always ends in an error.

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "67453c29-adf1-42c8-961d-d918ebbd6399",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBJV9TixAQQaFK2hx45pekrbWw4hwmNQedEsum5KtA2AcUn37pPFKvTsNq9zHMMsbMR7EwIAkvRLDjndLHt9JMqdQ/PHhNvNoL7Yqxi7kCROfUtwYdwLZNutUQpu7H1xUXZAy2fojsAP77ZfIt3366GikTKHYOf7tTHq0nxqW4wbI/z0tGr9tgEn6ux6xTbSZrLItqv4Y0Wi0GckkskOxch4EoibSEn10u+TdclIdhDwVkyEtJgvuExNQpKHsf+n9dZW/txw7pMweDIJXJz5CnhrNoWdxX/lHI4YpIvXqdJzR6BK4i3HOiEa3zJoQkX78BbQiqPjjZMQv+1JsPs7WzW7mkRTYl32PiBJi8T/1KXhjO2g5NsUUwi+jWmW2frjn/KhoACj7YttAWNMlJ79J4JULV7GDxJ5yAVwQWtGdnveE=",
            "body": "{\"params\" : {\n        \"path\" : {\n            \"userid\" : \"4711\"\n                }\n    ,        \"querystring\" : {\n          }\n    ,        \"header\" : {\n            \"Accept\" : \"*\\/*\"\n      ,            \"Accept-Encoding\" : \"gzip, deflate, br\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto\" : \"https\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer\" : \"true\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer\" : \"false\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer\" : \"false\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer\" : \"false\"\n      ,            \"CloudFront-Viewer-Country\" : \"DE\"\n      ,            \"Content-Type\" : \"application\\/json\"\n      ,            \"Host\" : \"api.example.com\"\n      ,            \"Postman-Token\" : \"a6609489-c851-4a97-b488-cf8436d83330\"\n      ,            \"Referer\" : \"http:\\/\\/api.example.com\\/dev\\/queue\\/sqs\\/4711\"\n      ,            \"User-Agent\" : \"PostmanRuntime\\/7.25.0\"\n      ,            \"Via\" : \"1.1 90cf045072373c2c672247de3161846f.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\"\n      ,            \"X-Amz-Cf-Id\" : \"GgzWFiE_xOfQs9y9_-_fa2BPPbpQYJPFp46wYaPNHTpX38MQUBj3UQ==\"\n      ,            \"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\" : \"Root=1-5ee0cd1a-a87ed5a83be891c04c50bd0a\"\n      ,            \"X-Forwarded-For\" : \"130.100.136.74, 130.176.0.156\"\n      ,            \"X-Forwarded-Port\" : \"443\"\n      ,            \"X-Forwarded-Proto\" : \"https\"\n                }\n          },\n    \"context\" : {\n    \"account-id\" : \"\",\n    \"api-id\" : \"gupxrscxx0\",\n    \"api-key\" : \"\",\n    \"authorizer-principal-id\" : \"\",\n    \"caller\" : \"\",\n    \"cognito-authentication-provider\" : \"\",\n    \"cognito-authentication-type\" : \"\",\n    \"cognito-identity-id\" : \"\",\n    \"cognito-identity-pool-id\" : \"\",\n    \"domain\" : \"api.example.com\",\n    \"http-method\" : \"POST\",\n    \"stage\" : \"dev\",\n    \"source-ip\" : \"130.100.136.74\",\n    \"user\" : \"\",\n    \"user-agent\" : \"PostmanRuntime/7.25.0\",\n    \"user-arn\" : \"\",\n    \"request-id\" : \"762ff394-3bfc-476b-9544-dc10ccac29cd\",\n    \"resource-id\" : \"4yw0f8\",\n    \"resource-path\" : \"/queue/sqs/{userid}\"\n    }, \"body\": {\"order\": {\r\n    \"access_allowed\": true,\r\n    \"business_name\": null,\r\n    \"business_vat_number\": null,\r\n    \"buyer_address1\": null,\r\n    \"buyer_address2\": null,\r\n    \"buyer_city\": null,\r\n    \"buyer_country\": \"GB\",\r\n    \"buyer_email\": \"mrbuyer@gmail.com\",\r\n    \"buyer_ip_address\": \"127.0.0.1\",\r\n    \"buyer_name\": \"Mr Buyer\",\r\n    \"buyer_postcode\": null,\r\n    \"buyer_region\": null,\r\n    \"cart\": {\r\n        \"cart_items\": [\r\n            {\r\n                \"download_attempts\": 3,\r\n                \"product\": {\r\n                    \"id\": 2811,\r\n                    \"license_type\": \"generated\",\r\n                    \"member_types\": [\r\n                        \"digital\"\r\n                    ],\r\n                    \"name\": \"My Product\",\r\n                    \"price\": \"£15.00\",\r\n                    \"product_image_url\": null,\r\n                    \"product_type\": \"digital\",\r\n                    \"shopify_variant_id\": null\r\n                },\r\n                \"quantity\": 1,\r\n                \"tax_rate\": 20.0,\r\n                \"valid_until\": \"2016-02-04T10:59:25Z\"\r\n            }\r\n        ],\r\n        \"completed_checkout_at\": \"2016-01-05T10:59:24Z\"\r\n    },\r\n    \"discount\": null,\r\n    \"dispatched_at\": null,\r\n    \"download_url\": \"http://transactions.sendowl.com/orders/123456/download/XXX\",\r\n    \"eu_resolved_country\": \"GB\",\r\n    \"eu_reverse_charge\": null,\r\n    \"for_subscription\": false,\r\n    \"gateway\": \"Stripe\",\r\n    \"gift_deliver_at\": null,\r\n    \"gift_order\": false,\r\n    \"giftee_email\": null,\r\n    \"giftee_name\": null,\r\n    \"id\": \"0000123456\",\r\n    \"licenses\": [],\r\n    \"order_custom_checkout_fields\": [],\r\n    \"paypal_email\": null,\r\n    \"price_at_checkout\": \"£15.00\",\r\n    \"receiver_email\": \"mrbuyer@gmail.com\",\r\n    \"receiver_name\": null,\r\n    \"settled_affiliate_fee\": \"£5.00\",\r\n    \"settled_currency\": \"GBP\",\r\n    \"settled_gateway_fee\": \"£0.38\",\r\n    \"settled_gross\": \"£18.00\",\r\n    \"settled_tax\": \"£3.00\",\r\n    \"state\": \"complete\",\r\n    \"subscription_management_url\": null,\r\n    \"tag\": null,\r\n    \"transactions\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"alternate_pay_method_note\": null,\r\n            \"created_at\": \"2016-01-05T10:59:24Z\",\r\n            \"gateway_transaction_id\": \"ch_fake001\",\r\n            \"net_price\": \"£15.60\",\r\n            \"payment_currency\": \"GBP\",\r\n            \"payment_gateway_fee\": \"£0.38\",\r\n            \"payment_gross\": \"£18.00\",\r\n            \"payment_tax\": \"£3.00\",\r\n            \"refund\": false\r\n        }\r\n    ],\r\n    \"unsubscribe_url\": \"http://transactions.sendowl.com/orders/123456/unsubscribe/XXX\",\r\n    \"validity_statement\": \"This link may be used up to 3 times before 2016-02-04 10:59:25 UTC when it will expire.\"\r\n}}}",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "AWSTraceHeader": "Root=1-5ee0cd1a-a87ed5a83be891c04c50bd0a",
                "SentTimestamp": "1591790874414",
                "SenderId": "AROAQJKS37YHIYFTSUYVY:BackplaneAssumeRoleSession",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1591790874421"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "965d776c1cbbbcbf669fde368a1d73f8",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:047118021238:Example-Test",
            "awsRegion": "eu-central-1"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I avoid the escaped (double serialized) data in the body? Lambda is running Python 3.8. Or is there any possibility to "repair" the body within Python?

Comment: You can't just run `json.loads(Records[0]['body'])`? Normally that's what's done in such a situation.

Comment: I thought so as well. But this gives me the body with single quotes (') which are not a valid JSON and thus, resulting in an error as well.

Comment: OK, foolish me. I found it. If I do like @Marcin says, I need to treat the resulting JSON separately. Then Python takes care of the single quotes. I.e. instead of `json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body']['params']['header']['Referer'])`, I need to `body=json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])
    print(body['params']['header']['Referer'])`

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make answer then if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments. The solution was to use:

```
body=json.loads(event['Records'][0]['body'])
print(body['params']['header']['Referer'])
```